# Python Logistic Regression (New to Data Science)

Tags: logistic-regression

I'm working on a project where there are two excel's one master.xls and another sample.xls. Master files has both the dependent and the independent variable. Whereas sample.xls has only the independent variable and need to create the independent variable (Either 1 or 0, 1 = Diabetic, 0 = Not Diabetic)

Now i need to use the master files to train the model and predict the independent variable for sample file. But not sure how to split the data between train and test . Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) function of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library to load the data (say master.xls)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('master.xls')
```

Lets say `y` is the dependent variable (i.e, ground truth value in Machine Learning terminology). Get the `y` column values & delete it from the `dataframe df`

```
y = df['y']
df = df.drop(['y'],axis=1)
```

Now use [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function of [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) to split the data into `train` & `test`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.3)
```

Now `X_train` will have `70%` of the total data points & `X_test` will have `30%` of the total data points. `y_train` & `y_test` are respective dependent variables of `train` & `test` data